# Weird C# GC behavior for Weakreferences and the null-conditional operator

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, null-conditional-operator

While creating a unit test for my C# code that works with `WeakReferences`, i ran into some weird GC behavior - weird because i have not been able to come up with an explanation for it.

The issue stems from using the `?.` **null conditional** operator on an object that was gotten from my weak reference after the GC is meant to have collected it.

Here's minimal code that replicates it:

```
    public class XYZClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        public void NormalBehavior()
        {
            var @ref = new WeakReference<XYZClass>(new XYZClass { Name = "bleh" });

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            XYZClass t;
            @ref.TryGetTarget(out t);

            Console.WriteLine(t == null); //outputs true
        }

        public void WeirdBehavior()
        {
            var @ref = new WeakReference<XYZClass>(new XYZClass { Name = "bleh" });

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            XYZClass t;
            @ref.TryGetTarget(out t);

            Console.WriteLine(t == null); //outputs false
            Console.WriteLine(t?.Name == null); //outputs false
        }
    }
```

The behavior wasn't exhibited when this code was run using linqpad. I also checked on the compiled IL code (using linqpad) and still couldn't **recognize** anything amiss.

Comment: Which part of your code is giving you trouble?

Comment: @DavidG I would say that he is interested in why the GC works in a different way if there is a `t?.` operator

Comment: Can repro in Debug build. Cannot repro in Release. GC and debug interact in odd ways which can extend object lifetimes.

Comment: If you're using LinqPad and get odd things happening, make sure you check the little icon on the bottom right of the window...

Comment: @DavidG the function "WeirdBehavior" is where the problem resides. t==null should be true, yet it is false. The test was originally run in visual studio 2015, that's where i noticed it, within my unit test, so i extracted this out and ran in a stand alone console app, in C# interactive, and in linqpad. Linqpad is the only place where the WeirdBehavior method didn't behave weirdly. The "weirdness", in my opinion, is the fact that the only difference between "NormalBehavior" and "WeirdBehavior" methods is the "Console.WriteLine(t?.Name == null);" line.

Comment: @Dantte But if you toggle the compiler optimisations on and off in LinqPad, you will see the output does change.

Comment: @DaviG, that's all well and good...and it brings us back to the crux of the matter: why does adding last line to the "WeirdBehavior" method make the outcome of the method different from the outcome of the "NormalBehavior" method. That's truly where the confusion is. Apologies if my question wasn't phrased correctly to highlight this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the null conditional operator. You can easily see this by replacing it with normal member access:

```
Console.WriteLine(t == null); //outputs false
Console.WriteLine(t.Name == null); //outputs false
```

The original reference to the new `XYZClass` object never goes "out of scope" in the debug build (and running under the debugger). Turn optimizations off in LINQPad, and you'll also see that `t` is not null. But note that all of this is an implementation detail - depending on particulars of your system, you can get either result (for example, I get what you get on 32-bit Debug builds, but not 64-bit Debug builds).

The only guarantee you get as to managed object lifetime in .NET is that a strong reference outside of a finalizer will prevent an object from being collected. Forget all deterministic memory management - it just isn't there. A .NET implementation that has no garbage collector at all would be perfectly valid.

So let's have a look at the code being generated on my machine in particular. In the 64-bit build, `t.Name == null` and `t?.Name == null` have exactly the same results (though of course `t.Name == null` will cause a `NullReferenceException` instead of returning true). What about the 32-bit build?

The `t.Name == null` part is substantially shorter:

```
00533111  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-44h]   ; t
00533114  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx  ; null check
00533116  call        00530D28  ; t.get_Name
0053311B  mov         dword ptr [ebp-54h],eax  ; Name string
0053311E  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-54h],0  ; is null?
00533122  sete        cl  
00533125  movzx       ecx,cl  
00533128  call        708B09F4
```

You can see that we use two registers (ecx and eax), and two stack slots (-44h and -54h). What about the `t?.Name == null` one?

```
001F3111  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-44h],0   ; is t null?
001F3115  jne         001F311F  
001F3117  nop  
001F3118  xor         edx,edx  
001F311A  mov         dword ptr [ebp-54h],edx  ; result is false
001F311D  jmp         001F312A  
001F311F  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-44h]  ; t
001F3122  call        001F0D28                 ; t.get_Name
001F3127  mov         dword ptr [ebp-54h],eax  
001F312A  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-54h],0    ; is name null?
001F312E  sete        cl  
001F3131  movzx       ecx,cl  
001F3134  call        708B09F4  
001F3139  nop
```

We're still using the same two stack slots, but another register is required - edx. Could this be what we're looking for? You betcha! If we look at how the object is originally created:

```
001F30A0  mov         ecx,2C0814h  
001F30A5  call        001330F4  ; new XYZClass
001F30AA  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax  ; tmp
001F30AD  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-48h]  
001F30B0  call        001F0D38  ; tmp.XYZClass()
001F30B5  mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[36B230Ch]  ; "bleh"
001F30BB  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-48h]  
001F30BE  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx  
001F30C0  call        001F0D30  ; tmp.set_Name("bleh")
001F30C5  nop  
001F30C6  mov         ecx,2C0858h  
001F30CB  call        710F9ECF  ; new WeakReference
001F30D0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax  
001F30D3  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
001F30D6  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-48h]  ; EDX references tmp!
001F30D9  call        709090B0  
001F30DE  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
001F30E1  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax
```

You can see that it so happens that the null-conditional version uses the same register that was used to hold the temporary reference to `XYZClass`. And that's where the difference stems from - the runtime cannot rule out that the `edx` access is a use of the temporary reference, so it plays it safe and keeps the object rooted, which prevents it from being collected.

The 64-bit version (and running without debugger attached) doesn't see the difference, because it reuses a different register - on my particular machine, the 64-bit version reuses `rcx` (which holds a reference to the `WeakReference`, not `XYZClass`), and the non-debugger 32-bit version reuses `eax` (which holds a reference to `"bleh"`). Since `edx` (and `rdx`) are never used in the method, the temporary reference isn't rooted anymore, and is free to be collected.

Why does the debugger version use `edx` in particular? Most likely, it's trying to be helpful. In the middle of the null conditional operator, you want to see the value of both `t` and `t?.Name`, so they better be accessible (you can see this in Locals as "XYZClass.Name.get returned "bleh" string").

Again, note that this is entirely implementation specific. The contract only specifies when an object *must not* be reclaimed - it doesn't say when it *will* be reclaimed.

Comment: Many thanks for the thoroughly detailed response. Precisely what i needed!